# Cannot extract the embedded font - Code Igniter and dompdf

Tags: codeigniter, dompdf

Following the instruction in this link ( https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/PDF-generation-using-dompdf ), I always encounter an error when opening the pdf file created. The error message is:"Cannot extract embedded font 'TradeGothicLT-CondEighteen'.Some characters may not display or print correctly. " and when i click  OK, the pdf displays black background and when i start highlighting the body, it captures the text but text are in black font-color. what should I do to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

There may be something wrong with your font cache, located at dompdf/lib/fonts/dompdf_font_family_cache.php (though the exact file name depends on your release and whether you have loaded fonts). This file tells dompdf what fonts are available for use in the PDF. If this file references a font that isn't actually available you can run into major issues on viewing. You may need to re-load your font files. Take a look at the [Unicode how-to](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo) for an overview of using embedded fonts. This document hasn't been updated to reflect changes implemented in dompdf 0.6.0 beta 3, but the information is still pertinent.